# What is the difference between data and data.frame in R?

Tags: r

I know `data.frame` is a 2-D matrix with columns with different types. I think `data` is another type of data structure in `R`, which can take multiple `data.frame`s.

In `RStudio`, now I have two `data`: `dcd` and `pdb`:

[image]

I was trying to understand the properties of them:

```
> dcd

   Total Frames#: 101
   Total XYZs#:   19851,  (Atoms#:  6617)

    [1]  65.59  84.65  90.92  <...>  59.76  55.48  83.68  [2004951] 

+ attr: Matrix DIM = 101 x 19851

> class(dcd)
[1] "xyz"    "matrix"

> dcd$xyz
Error in dcd$xyz : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

> pdb

 Call:  read.pdb(file = pdbfile)

   Total Models#: 1
     Total Atoms#: 6598,  XYZs#: 19794  Chains#: 2  (values: L H)

     Protein Atoms#: 6598  (residues/Calpha atoms#: 442)
     Nucleic acid Atoms#: 0  (residues/phosphate atoms#: 0)

     Non-protein/nucleic Atoms#: 0  (residues: 0)
     Non-protein/nucleic resid values: [ none ]

   Protein sequence:
      DIQMTQSPSSLSASVGDRVTITCKASQNVRTVVAWYQQKPGKAPKTLIYLASNRHTGVPS
      RFSGSGSGTDFTLTISSLQPEDFATYFCLQHWSYPLTFGQGTKVEIKRTVAAPSVFIFPP
      SDEQLKSGTASVVCLLNNFYPREAKVQWKVDNALQSGNSQESVTEQDSKDSTYSLSSTLT
      LSKADYEKHKVYACEVTHQGLSSPVTKSFNRGECEVQLVESGGGL...<cut>...TSAA

+ attr: atom, xyz, calpha, call

> class(pdb)
[1] "pdb" "sse"

> pdb$xyz

   Total Frames#: 1
   Total XYZs#:   19794,  (Atoms#:  6598)

    [1]  24.33  14.711  -3.854  <...>  -34.374  -6.315  14.986  [19794] 

+ attr: Matrix DIM = 1 x 19794
```

My questions are:

1. Is `dcd` similar to a matrix with 101 rows and 19851 columns?
2. `class(dcd)` outputs `"xyz"` and `"matrix"`, does it mean the `dcd` belongs to both `"xyz"` and `"matrix"` types in the same time?
3. How can I create a `data` like `pdb` which includes multiple `data.frame`?

e.g. if I have

```
students <- data.frame(c("Cedric","Fred","George"),c(3,2,2))
names(students) <- c("name", "year")
teachers <- data.frame(c("John","Alice","Mike"),c(6,9,5))
names(teachers) <- c("name", "year")
```

how can I combine `students` and `teachers` into a `data` called `people`, so that I can use `people$students` or `people$teachers`?

Comment: perhaps you need a `list` ?  `list(students = students, teachers = teachers)`

Comment: I see, so the `data` in `RStudio` means anything else except `values`. The `dcd` and `pdb` are just `list`?

Comment: "data" is just a label that RStudio uses for certain things in the global environment. It is not a technical term like "matrix" or "dataframe" in R. "xyz" seems to be a custom class, perhaps defined in some package that you are using but neglected to mention. In R's S3 object system, "class" is just an attribute which is used in method dispatch.

Comment: So `dcd` belongs to both `xyz` and `matrix` type, while `pdb` belongs to both `pdb` and `sse` type. `pdb` is also not a `list`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're asking how to create a `dataframe` named `people`, so you can access the names of the people using `people$students` or `people$teachers`, then the code to achieve that is:

```
people <- data.frame(students = students$name, teachers = teachers$name)
people$students
```

`people` would be a dataframe that looks like this:
[image]

If you want a `list`, you can create a list object like the following:

```
people2 <- as.list(c("students" = students, "teachers" = teachers))
people2$students.name
# returns [1] Cedric Fred   George
```

And `people2` would be a list:
[image]

See the `$` (dollar sign) next to each item in the list? That tells you how to access them. If you wanted `teachers.name`, then `print(people2$teachers.name)` will do that for you.

As for your other questions:

1. Is dcd similar to a matrix with 101 rows and 19851 columns?

You can verify the dimension of a matrix-like object using `dim()`, `ncol()` or `nrow()`. In your case yes it has 101 rows and 19851 columns.

2. `class(dcd)` outputs "xyz" and "matrix", does it mean the dcd belongs to both "xyz" and "matrix" types in the same time?

Simplistically, you can think of it inheriting a `matrix` class as well as `xyz`. You may want to read about [classes and inheritance in R](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/class.html).

3. How can I create a data like pdb which includes multiple data.frame?

Look at my code above. `people2 <- as.list(c("students" = students, "teachers" = teachers))` creates a `list` of "multiple" dataframes.

Comment: so `pdb` is also not a `list`?

Comment: Definitely look like a list to me, but I don't have a sample of your data. I recommend you try `class(pdb)`. A `list` in R can contain multiple objects of different classes. So your `pdb` object can contain a dataframe, a matrix etc. Try `class(pdb[[1]])` and `class(pdb[[2]])` and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: `class(pdb)`: `"pdb" "sse"`; `class(pdb[[1]])`: `"data.frame"`; `class(pdb[[2]])`: `"xyz"    "matrix"`; `class(pdb[[3]])`: `"logical"`; `class(pdb[[4]])`: `"call"`.

Comment: another question, why should use two layers of `[]`? The `class(pdb[n])` always gives `"list"` for `n` with any number.

Comment: So `pdb` and `sse` are classes defined from the package author. It inherits a `list` type, but it's always good practice to read the documentation from the package to be sure. And what you saw reinforces what I said earlier: that a list can contain multiple items, each of different class. In your case, your list has a data frame, matrix, logical vector and a function call.

Comment: When subsetting a list, using one square bracket [] returns the result as a list. Using [[]] returns the result itself, and not the list. Hope this clarifies, but tons of resources out there if you want to read more: http://uc-r.github.io/lists_subsetting

Comment: My pleasure! Good luck with the project!